# I'm trying to submit a form when selecting a radio button and not successful javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

This was my last attempt, and I haven't been successful.

```
if(document.querySelectorAll("input[name='myRadioButton']").checked) {   
  alert("checked");
}
```

It must be something simple for JavaScript experts.
Why is JavaScript so difficult?

PLEASE no jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use event listener to handle the input change like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="radio" name="myradio" />
    <input type="radio" name="myradio" />
    <input type="radio" name="myradio" />
  </body>
</html>
<script>
  let radio = document.getElementsByName("myradio");

  for (let i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) {
    radio[i].addEventListener("input", () => {
      alert("checked");
    });
  }
</script>
```